# Spring-Data-Neo4j: "Factory method 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' threw exception", empty JSON

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am new to spring-data and neo4j, so if there is something painfully bad about my code please say.

I want to deploy my application to heroku, however I cannot get remote neo4j connections to work. I have tried

- Remote connection to a local docker image (which works in browser)
- Local server
- Heroku add-on (Graphstory)

Sadly, they all give the same [exception](http://pastebin.com/BEPHfAyy), the most important being:

```
Factory method 'typeRepresentationStrategyFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON ''
```

You can see my Neo4j Spring Configuration [here](http://pastebin.com/hZPfLGye) (`unit` profile is for unit testing) and part of my pom is [here](http://pastebin.com/UiKGbKfF).

- Neo4j docker image version: 2.3.3
- Neo4j local version: 2.3.3

GraphEntity model (Comment) [here](http://pastebin.com/WS3tYhys)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out my dependencies are incompatible with the Neo4j server I think.

Furthermore the only compatible version is on neo4j's private maven repository.

[Flavorwocky](https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky/tree/sdn) by luanne (not me) is a good reference for how it should look

Also go and have a look at [Neo4j OGM documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/stable/) if you are here.